# SwiftUI TextField freezes when deleting first character

Tags: swiftui

When specifying a minimumScaleFactor for a TextField in SwiftUI the TextField behaves normally while you enter text and reduces the font as specified when the content does not fit the TextView. However, if you start deleting characters everything works as usual until you delete the first character. Everything freezes.

At the beginning I though it was something in the way I was handling the variable that stores the text that in my application I have it as an ObservedObject. However, after debugging the frozen app I noticed that the code was circling around the drawing of the TextField over and over, function after function everything pointed to an error in the drawing of the object on the screen.

The following code illustrates the issue. The TextField works perfectly when you enter characters and delete them until you get to the first one. The it freezes.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

@State var sensorNumber: String = ""

    var body: some View {
        TextField("WC0.000.000.000", text: $sensorNumber)
        .padding(.all, 5.0)
        .font(Font.custom("Helvetica", size:40.0))
        .minimumScaleFactor(0.90)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be related to the interaction of the Custom Font. Obviously, my application is using custom fonts but here I just wanted to simplify the code.

This code does not fail if you don't use a custom font or if you don't specify a minimumScaleFactor. I have found a workaround that is not very elegant but it works until Apple fixes this bug:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

@State var sensorNumber: String = ""

    var body: some View {
        TextField("WC0.000.000.000", text: $sensorNumber)
        .padding(.all, 5.0)
        .font(Font.custom("Helvetica", size:40.0))
        .minimumScaleFactor(sensorNumber.count < 2 ? 1.0 : 0.90)
    }
}
```

I am submitting a radar to Apple but looking for a better solution for the problem here.